# Typescript and Angular: typeError: 'x' is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a button in my schedule.component.html, and link its click with a function defined in the associated schedule.component.ts.

The button is created with the following code:

```
<button type="submit"
                (click)="onSubmitExporter2()">
                Propose passes
 </button>
```

and it appears correctly, but when clicked nothing happens, and the console gives me the error:
TypeError: onSubmitExporter2() is not a function.

My method is the following:

```
public onSubmitExporter2(): void {
        console.log('onSubmitExporter2() called');
     const exporter: Exporter = {
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    successMessage: '',
    error: false,
    errorMessage: '',
    info: '',
    exportTime: '',
    exportStatus: '',
    name: 'Download Proba-3 Pass Plan',
    endpoint: '',
    description: '',
    returnFile: false,
    parameters: []
  };
    const exporterPath = 'adapter/gsms/exporter/proba3_pass_plan_export'; // Specify the exporter path
    const queryParams = new Map<string, string>(); // Optional: Add query parameters if needed
    queryParams.set('download', 'true');

 

    this.opsWebDataService.exporter(exporterPath, queryParams).subscribe(
      (r) => {
       if (!exporter.returnFile) {
            exporter.info = r.info;
            exporter.exportTime = r.last_export;
            exporter.exportStatus = r.status;
          } else {
            const disposition = r.headers.get('content-disposition');
            let filename = disposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
            filename = filename.replace(/"/g, '');

 

            const file = new File([r.body], filename,
               { type: r.headers.get('content-type') });
            saveAs(file);
          }

 

          this.onSuccessExport(exporter);
},
      (error) => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and it is inside the export class DataTransfer.

Do you have any solutions? Thanks

Comment: is DataTransfer an angular component, with its @Component annotation, linking the component to the HTML ?

Comment: try this `<form [formGroup]="exporterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitExporter2()">
<button type="submit"> Propose passes </button></form>` or remove  type="submit"

Comment: I solved the issue by defining this method inside the right class; I have two classes in my .ts, and this method was defined in the data-transfer class. For some reason, it worked only as soon as I defined it in the schedule class.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by defining this method inside the right class; I have two classes in my .ts, and this method was defined in the data-transfer class. For some reason, it worked only as soon as I defined it in the schedule class. Thank you for your help!